# Difference between ArrayList<String> and ArrayList<>?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, compilation

1:

```
private List<String> blacklist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

2:

```
private List<String> blacklist = new ArrayList<>();
```

Are there any advantages using the first or the second one in compile time or performance in nanoseconds?

Comment: The latter is exclusively Java 7+, the other one isn't. Performance in *nano*seconds?

Comment: So you want to gain 1 nanosecond? At compile time? Also, @DaveNewton, the first one is Java 7+ too!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Clarified for the pedantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both statements are semantically the same.**

The 2nd example is using Diamond operator from Java 7 and so will be a little bit slower at compile time. At runtime they will have exactly the same performance as the generics information will be completely removed.

Comment: You probably won't notice the "little bit slower" compile time. The diamond operator is a simple type inference feature of the compiler.

Comment: Not necessarily, it is a little bit more complicated as you can use the wildcards as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. In the second case, the compiler infers the generic type of the `ArrayList`.